# Elasticsearch, search for domains in urls

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

We index HTML documents which may include links to other documents. We're using elasticsearch and things are pretty smooth for most keyword searches, which is great.

Now, we're adding more complex searches similar to Google `site:` or `link:` searches: basically we want to retrieve documents which point to eithr specific urls or even domains. (If document A has a link to `http://a.site.tld/path/`, the search `link:http://a.site.tld` should yield it.).

And we're now trying what would be the best way to achieve this.
So far, we have extracted the links from the documents and added a `links` field to our document. We setup the `links` to be not analyzed. We can then do search that match the exact url  `link:http://a.site.tld/path/` But of course `link:http://a.site.tld` does not yield anything.

Our initial idea would be to create a new field `linkedDomains` which would work similarly... but there may exist better solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Path Hierarchy Tokenizer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html):

Define a mapping as follows:

```
PUT /link-demo
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "path-analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "path_hierarchy"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {      
      "properties": {
        "link": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "path-analyzer"          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index a doc:

```
POST /link-demo/doc
{
    link: "http://a.site.tld/path/"
}
```

The following term query returns the indexed doc:

```
POST /link-demo/_search?pretty
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "link": {
              "value": "http://a.site.tld"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

To get a feel for how this is being indexed:

```
GET link-demo/_analyze?analyzer=path-analyzer&text="http://a.site.tld/path"&pretty
```

Shows the following:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "\"http:",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 6,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "\"http:/",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "\"http://a.site.tld",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 18,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "\"http://a.site.tld/path\"",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 24,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```